# check Parametrized type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an object with a generic field

```
public class MyObject<T> {
   private String field1;
   private T field2;
   private String field3;

   public MyObject(String field1, T value, String field) {
   //set fields
   }
   //getters, and setters
}
```

These objects are instantiated by:

```
MyObject objStr = new MyObject<String>("value1", "value2", "value3");
MyObject objInt = new MyObject<Integer>("value1", 343, "value3");
```

I have a method in another class that manipulates the generic field of the above class depending on whether it is a String or Integer:

```
public class Worker {
   ...
   public String doSomething (MyObject myObj) {
      Object field2 = myObj.getField2();
      if(field2 instanceof String) {...}
      else if(field2 instanceof Integer) {...}
      ....
   }
}
```

Currently I use the `instanceof` feature but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this since I already know the object `MyObject` is parametrized to either `String` or `Integer`

Thanks!

Comment: This defeats the purpose of genericizing types if all you're going to do is `if(... instanceof ...)` You're better off not even using generics and instead, in MyObject, (which I assume has an array or arraylist of the objects) define that array as `Object[]` or `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: I figured that was the case.. that is why I am asking if there is another way taking advantage of the Generics feature @KodleeYin

Comment: It really depends on what you're implementing, but as it stands, you already know what you're implementing. Generics are only useful when you don't know what types/values are going to be used (say you're building a framework that other people are using, you don't know what other people might place inside your object, so you'd use generics). In your case, however, it seems like you already know what types you're going to be using, so generics aren't beneficial to you.